# How to add custom prefix to every syslog line automatically?

Tags: nginx, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I would like to have a specific prefix in front of every single syslog line in my Ubuntu servers (running nginx). The prefix should take the value from either some env-variable or one specific folder name. How to do it?

I see there is a [syslog configuration file](https://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf) present but didn't see possibilities how to configure this accordingly. Found some rsyslog configuration from `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and as well from `/etc/rsyslog.d/*` but no clue how to configure it there.

**EXAMPLE:**

Let's say I have env variable evaluated as follows: `PLUGIN_VERSION=32k0dkwfrghhaq3faiwejaf932`.
I would now like this `32k0dkwfrghhaq3faiwejaf932` to be present in front of every single line in my syslog file.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/979959/rsyslog-specify-action-parameters-from-environment-variables